# Crear una tabla de productos que actualice el inventario

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, visual-basic

es mi primera pregunta asi que no se si sera del todo entendible.
tengo una sistema mysql con una base de datos sobre una empresa ligada a un form de visual basic sobre ventas, quisiera saber como hacer que al hacer una compra de un producto en la tabla de productos la cantidad del producto reste la cantidad comprada.

por ejemplo:

tengo 100 de zanahorias y alguien compro 50, entonces me quedan 50 zanahorias en la tabla productos

este es el código de la tabla:

```
create table productos
(
    Idproductos int not null auto_increment primary key,
    Codigo varchar(15) not null,
    Producto varchar(50) not null,
    Cantidad int not null,
    Precio float,
    tipoprod varchar(50)
);
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, Idtipoprod) values("003","Simparica",2,150,"Vacuna antirrabica");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, Idtipoprod) values("015","Seresto",5,450,"Collar antipulgas");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, Idtipoprod) values("063","Pet Pectillin",3,75,"Medicamento intestinal");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, Idtipoprod) values("074","Omega Vet",4,230,"Suplemento");
insert into productos(Codigo, Producto, Cantidad, Precio, Idtipoprod) values("012","ActiPet",1,100,"Vitaminas");
select * from productos;
```

si alguien pudiera ayudarme se los agradecería mucho!

Comment: es una consulta de tipo update me parece lo quie tienes que hacer, con los nuevos datos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.